# How to pass a prop method with react-router | render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been looking around at various potential solutions on StackOverflow / elsewhere, and as of yet I've been unable to find a solution that I feel applies to my problem specifically.

I've seen several posts mentioning using the Router `render` method, but I can't seem to wrap my head around I would pass a method from a separate component into another component using this approach.

For instance, I am attempting to have a method in my `App` component get passed into my `Form` component as a prop. When the form in `Form` is submitted, it should invoke the passed in method updating the state in `App` with the inputs from the form.

The method in `App` is called `accountDetails`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: this.props.location.state.username,
    color: this.props.location.state.color || "red",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    contact: ""
  };

  toJobBoard = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: `jobs/${this.state.username}`,
      state: { username: this.state.username }
    });
  };

  //this is the method I would like to pass into the Form component via Router
  accountDetails = (firstName, lastName) => {
    this.setState({ firstName, lastName });
  };

// + irrelevant code
```

What my Router currently looks like, I know what I have entered in `render` is nonsensical, I'm toying around with it at this point.

```
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/page/:usernameId" component={App} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/page/jobs/:usernameId"
        render={props => (
          <Form {...props} accountDetails={App.accountDetails} />
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

TLDR;
I want to pass a method in one component, into another as a prop, using Router. When the component is invoked in the other component it should update the state in the first component.

--edit my Router is the top-level component. App and Form are both paths.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Router Component inside the App Component? if yes then just pass the method as a prop to the Router and it should be fine.

```
`const Router = (props) => (

  <BrowserRouter>

    <Switch>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />

      <Route exact path="/page/:usernameId" component={App} />

      <Route exact path="/page/jobs/:usernameId" render={() => ( <Form accountDetails={props.accountDetails} />)}/>

    </Switch>

  </BrowserRouter>

);`
```

Comment: Unfortunately my Router is the top-level component and App is one of the paths for it. I'll update my post to reflect that.

Comment: Aah.. You would either have to lift the App to top level then or use a state manager like redux in that case. As far as I know you cannot communicate between two sibling components.

Comment: Amit is correct. The behaviour you want can only be solved by having the method(s) binded and passed down from a parent component of <App/> and <Form/>. I would suggest creating a Component that sits above the <Switch/> but below <BrowserRouter/>. Or if you want adding some sort of global store like redux but that might not be worth the hassle if your app is small.